# AHK How to make LAlt+key work while loop is up?

Tags: loops, autohotkey

i got this loop that works pretty well, but i cant make LAlt+key work while the loop is active.
Maybe pause it while LAlt is down and continue the loop when LAlt come back up.
Any suggestions to make LAlt work with another key at the same time while the loop is active?

```
    loop                                    
{
    PixelGetColor, Color, 1, 1439, RGB
    if Color = 0x000000
    {
    SendInput {Del}
    Sleep 80
    }
    else
    {
    Sleep 10
    }
    
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a Timer instead of a loop. These are much more easily interrupted. Here is an example of how you might do this with your example above:

```
setTimer, CheckPixelColor, 250 ; milliseconds

Return ; end auto-execute section

Thread, Interrupt, 20, 3 ; see if that works
CheckPixelColor:
if (getKeyState( "LAlt", "P")) {
    Return ; do not execute below code
}
PixelGetColor, Color, 1, 1439, RGB
if Color = 0x000000
{
    SendInput {Del}
    Sleep 150
} else {
    Sleep 10
}
return
```

a Timer will just do the "label" action every number of milliseconds you set when you turn it on with "setTimer".

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still cant make LAlt+key work while the {Del} spam is on. Maybe another script that pauses or suspend all other scripts while i press LAlt.

Comment: Try using #Installkeybdhook at top of the script and try again. Not sure why it isn’t working.

Comment: I added an edit that should make the thread more able to interrupted by pressing the LAlt key. Some settings on it may need to be changed. Take a look at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Thread.htm